# Running a Python app on real Android phone

Tags: android, python

In order to develop an Android app using Python, I need to install Python for Android and SL4A on my computer to be used with the Android emulator. My question is, when I distribute this app to actual users/phones, do the phones need to get Python for Android and SL4A explicitly? Or is the supporting infrastructure built into Android devices? Or is there a way to package the Python application where the users do not have to get SL4A and Python for Android in order to run the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users have to install SL4A and the language plugin (python?) on their phones, this is not a built-in functionality.

Since the source code is available, it's possible to create combined application, which includes your scripts and SL4A/python code, but in my opinion this defies the purpose of scripting in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Instructions on redistributing your script to run on devices other than your development one are here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/SharingScripts

You can wrap them in a template project and build a stand alone apk.